# Remove special characters in sed script

Tags: linux, perl, unix, sed

I'm having a hard time removing º and ª in a sentence.

For instance, given this line:

> s. ex.ª mandava: e como esse inverno ia seco

I would like to remove "s. ex.ª", ending up with:

> mandava: e como esse inverno ia seco

I have tried (without success) the following regex:

> s/s. ex.\ª//g
>   s/s. ex.ª//g
>   s/s. ex.[ºª]//g

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Quick questions to make this easier to answer: What encoding is used by your source file? Did you use `use utf8;`? Did you decode your input?

Comment: You were right, the input file was in latin1, instead of utf8.

Comment: What do you get instead of the expected output?

Comment: Thank you all for your replies, but I managed to solve my problem.  Like @ikegami mentioned a mismatched encoding was the problem.   Will mark it as solved after the 8h minimum limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the input file to utf-8 solved my problem, marking the question as solved.
Thanks again to @ikegami, for pointing me in the right direction.